# How to attach a .csv (generated by php) via using SendGrid?

Tags: php, sendgrid

I leave a simple text for fast reading.

I'm trying to figure out how to send a csv file via sendgrid, csv is used with array, it's

```
fputcsv($output, array('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3'));
```

It's not a real file from server, simply to create file and export data to users.

The problem is... addAttachment or setAttachment returned some errors, they requiere where to find a file from path or directory.

How to attach a file without requesting an existing file from directory via sendgrid?

EDIT:

```
        //Function to generate csv file
            private function array2csv($array) {
            if (count($array) == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            $lista = $array;
            ob_start();
            $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
            foreach ($array as $campos) {
                fputcsv($fp, $campos);
            }
            fclose($fp);
            return ob_get_clean();
        }

    //Call a function to send csv file
        public function sendCSVFile(){

            $data = $this->reqProducts();
            //prepareParams is csv templating and formatting function.
            $products = $this->prepareParams($data);
            $products = $this->array2csv($products);

            $body = "Hello, you have an attached file."


            $email = new SendGrid\Email();
            $email
              ->addTo('foo@bar.com')
              ->setFrom('me@bar.com')
              ->setSubject($body)
              ->setText($body)
              ->setHtml('<strong>Hello World!</strong>')
              ->addAttachment($products);

        }
```

Error output is:

[image]

Comment: Can you include the code you're calling SendGrid with?

Comment: @wogsland it's a big code, give me some minutes to simplify my code.

Comment: @wogsland done, see edited post

Comment: @wogsland isn't possible to generate file from a string to attach with sendgrid?